# Can I use graphql-dotnet without Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, graphql-dotnet

Can I use graphql-dotnet without Entity Framework?

I'm currently looking at this repository https://github.com/mmacneil/fullstack-jobs, and noticed that it is using EF. And everywhere I look on the internet for examples, I can only find graphql-dotnet implementations with EF.

I want to use graphql-dotnet in an existing database structure where EF is not suitable. Writing direct SQL is how I would want the application to work. Does anyone have any examples?

I don't understand how graphql-dotnet ties together with the database in the repository that I have linked

Comment: Have you done this for ADO.NET ? In case of yes, can you provide implementations for the interfaces ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use GraphQL without EF. I did some investigation regarding your github link and what I've found.

First of all you should check these interfaces:

[IRepository](https://github.com/mmacneil/fullstack-jobs/blob/master/src/Backend/FullStackJobs.GraphQL/FullStackJobs.GraphQL.Core/Interfaces/Gateways/Repositories/IRepository.cs)

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    Task<T> GetById(int id);
    Task<List<T>> ListAll();
    Task<T> GetSingleBySpec(ISpecification<T> spec);
    Task<List<T>> List(ISpecification<T> spec);
    Task<T> Add(T entity);
    Task Update(T entity);
    Task Delete(T entity);
}
```

[IJobRepository](https://github.com/mmacneil/fullstack-jobs/blob/master/src/Backend/FullStackJobs.GraphQL/FullStackJobs.GraphQL.Core/Interfaces/Gateways/Repositories/IJobRepository.cs)

```
public interface IJobRepository : IRepository<Job>
{
}
```

These interfaces (mostly only IRepository) define a contract how you can use your db.
Next you need to check these classes:
[EfRepository](https://github.com/mmacneil/fullstack-jobs/blob/master/src/Backend/FullStackJobs.GraphQL/FullStackJobs.GraphQL.Infrastructure/Data/Repositories/EfRepository.cs)
I've omitted some implementaion details since they are not critical for understanding

```
    public abstract class EfRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        protected readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;

        protected EfRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext)
        {
            _appDbContext = appDbContext;
        }

        public virtual async Task<T> GetById(int id)
        {
            return await _appDbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(id);
        }

        public async Task<List<T>> ListAll()
        {
            return await _appDbContext.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<T> GetSingleBySpec(ISpecification<T> spec)
        {
            //implementation omitted
        }

        public async Task<List<T>> List(ISpecification<T> spec)
        {
           //implementation omitted
        }

        public async Task<T> Add(T entity)
        {
            //implementation omitted
        }

        public async Task Update(T entity)
        {
           //implementation omitted
        }

        public async Task Delete(T entity)
        {
            //implementation omitted
        }
    }
```

[JobRepository](https://github.com/mmacneil/fullstack-jobs/blob/master/src/Backend/FullStackJobs.GraphQL/FullStackJobs.GraphQL.Infrastructure/Data/Repositories/JobRepository.cs)

```
 public sealed class JobRepository : EfRepository<Job>, IJobRepository
    {
        public JobRepository(AppDbContext appDbContext) : base(appDbContext)
        {
        }
    }
```

These classes contain implementation of the interfaces described above and EfRepository contains all code to work with db. In this case we have EF, but it is possible to use everything you want, any db or collections and etc.

So the next what we need is [ContextServiceLocator](https://github.com/mmacneil/fullstack-jobs/blob/master/src/Backend/FullStackJobs.GraphQL/FullStackJobs.GraphQL.Infrastructure/GraphQL/Helpers/ContextServiceLocator.cs) (If to be more precise we need JobRepository field here)

```
public class ContextServiceLocator
    {
        public IJobRepository JobRepository => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IJobRepository>();

        public IHumanizer Humanizer => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHumanizer>();

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public ContextServiceLocator(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
    }
```

And the last but not the least is [FullStackJobsQuery](https://github.com/mmacneil/fullstack-jobs/blob/master/src/Backend/FullStackJobs.GraphQL/FullStackJobs.GraphQL.Infrastructure/GraphQL/FullStackJobsQuery.cs)

```
public class FullStackJobsQuery : ObjectGraphType
    {
        public FullStackJobsQuery(ContextServiceLocator contextServiceLocator)
        {
            FieldAsync<JobType>("job",
                arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<IntGraphType> { Name = "id" }),               
                resolve: async context => await contextServiceLocator.JobRepository.GetSingleBySpec(new JobSpecification(j => j.Id == context.GetArgument<int>("id", default))));

            FieldAsync<ListGraphType<JobSummaryType>>("employerJobs",
             resolve: async context =>
             {
                 // Extract the user id from the name claim to fetch the target employer's jobs
                 var jobs = await contextServiceLocator.JobRepository.List(new JobSpecification(j => j.Employer.Id == context.GetUserId()));
                 return jobs.OrderByDescending(j => j.Modified);
             });

            FieldAsync<ListGraphType<JobSummaryType>>("publicJobs",
                resolve: async context =>
                {
                    // Fetch published Jobs from all employers
                    var jobs = await contextServiceLocator.JobRepository.List(new JobSpecification(j => j.Status == Status.Published));
                    return jobs.OrderByDescending(j => j.Modified);
                });
        }
    }
```

In this class you can see how to use contextServiceLocator.JobRepository in order to resolve graphql field.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for taking the time to answer :) This is a big help!

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that using graphql-dotnet without EF is completely doable. The problem is, setting up an example is not trivial and requires a bit of infrastructure. I would recommend that you attempt an implementation on your own, and as you run into difficulties switching out EF code with your own, you post a question with the specifics of what you are trying to do.

The main difference in implementation will be how you handle the resolver in each field you define in your schema. You can access the data in any way you wish. You just need to ensure that the results you provide back in your methods match the types you defined in your graphql schema object.

I really can't give you much more detail than that without at least some initial framework to build upon.